# Mule Anypoint timestamp flowVar does not filter payload by LastModifiedDate

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio

I'm trying to create a data sync using Mule Soft so that Db1 is checked for any updates based on LastModified Date and if so the updates are applied to Db2. 
I've got the script to work to a point where when the script is first started, the data is copied from Db1 to Db2. After which the script constantly updating the records in Db2. (Below is my flow Diagram)

[image]
I've tried to setup recordVars in the message enricher (in Batch_Step) to see if records exists and route them accordingly in Choice (in Batch_Step1).
I've also enabled water mark in Poll for timestamp but nothing is working to avoid constant updating of inserted records.

Below are screenshot of my configs:

**Watermark Setup:**
[image]

**Db1 query:**
[image]

**BatchStep Accept Expression:**
[image]

**Message Enricher:**
[image]

**Choice Setup:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add LastModifiedDate in the Select statement from Db1 so watermark will able to access the field payload.LastModifiedDate.

Also, what is your query in Db2 batch_step? check it, cause it might always getting results that possibly caused to always have payload.size > 0.

Comment: Thanks! Adding LastModifiedDate to the Select statement of Db1 solved it. Now it doesn't return payload unless a newer LastModifiedDate is found in Db1.